# regular expression for no blank space b/w text

Tags: asp.net, regex

Please tell me how to check regular expression for no blank space  b/w text.

Comment: I'm not sure about what your question is. Could you give an example what you want to find with the regular expression and what not?

Answer (score 28):

If you mean "What's the reqular expression to check there is no white space in a string", the following pattern will work:

```
^[\S]*$
```

This will find any string that only contains non-white space (spaces, new lines, tabs, etc).

Comment: simply use \s to match if space exist and then use not() or  !() to reverse might be quicker.

Comment: I think the `\S` shorthand is better, because using `!(\s)` you might miss other characters, resp. it might not work in some context, like my Netbeans text editor :). http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is the regular expression you are looking for but, `[:space:]` will match any whitespace character, while `[:blank:]` will match space and tab characters only.

Both are used inside square brackets, e.g. `[[:space:]]`