# Regular Expression to avoid space in asp.net textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have lot of aspx pages with textboxes and I am using VB.NET.

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtADHD" MaxLength="6"></asp:TextBox>
```

I am using an regular expression validator

```
ValidationExpression="^\d+$"
```

This only helps me when there is space between two numbers and not when there is just space.
(1 space 1) it regular expression is validated.

Space and then I enter 1 the regular expression is not fired. 
Is there an easy way to avoid space or modify this regular expression?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regular expression for no blank space b/w text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446108/regular-expression-for-no-blank-space-b-w-text)

Comment: This validation works for space between two numbers. My question was to avoid space in the begining of the text box.

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about spaces, then you can use the `String.Replace()` method, like this:

```
Dim replacedString As String = txtADHD.Text.Replace(" ", String.Empty)
```

Note: This will not take out new lines, tabs, etc., but if you have single line text, then that should not be an issue.

Comment: This is what I was thinking as well.  Personally, I really don't like forms that force a particular format to data entry (like phone or ssn's).  This type of data has well known formats so stripping out things like spaces, periods, dashes etc and formatting the way the system wants should be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

"What's the reqular expression to check there is no white space in a string", the following pattern will work:

```
ValidationExpression="^[\S]*$"
```

This will find any string that only contains non-white space (spaces, new lines, tabs, etc).