# Regex not working and always detecting match

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, ios6

Please tell me what is wrong with this regex. I need to have only alphabets and no digits at all.

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^(?!\\s*$)()[a-zA-Z,\\w,.\\s,-]{2,50}$"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionUseUnicodeWordBoundaries
                                                                         error:&error];
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:text
                                                    options:0
                                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];

if (numberOfMatches == 1) {
    return  nil;
} else {
    return NSLocalizedString(@"name.validation.alert1", nil);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-only-letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `.` in the regex, which allows also a digit.
Please reconsider changing regex like this:

```
^(?=\\S)()[A-Za-z\\s]{2,50}$
```

It would be nice, if you could paste here some string you evaluate.
You can also try your regex online in site like: regexpal.com
Cheers.

Comment: nope, still the same problem. getting no error for the following : test1

Comment: Please post at least one valid expression/string for regex here, which should give no error for You.

Comment: this regex works fine on javascript on website link http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html. But it seems Objective C specific issue.

Comment: The correct string : Peter Parker. Incorrect String : Peter1 Parker

Comment: I'll try to make one regex for You, in the mean time please see the site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276246/how-to-write-regular-expressions-in-objective-c-nsregularexpression

Comment: And this site also may be helpful: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: well, it seems to be working (hopefully in all the cases). Thanks a lot @Kamil :)

Comment: Maybe this regex will work for You? `^(?=\S)()[A-Za-z\s]{2,50}$`

Comment: In the previous one I forgot that You may not want to have spaces at the beginning of the words, right?

Comment: Yes...I do not want spaces at the beginning. ^(?=\S)()[A-Za-z\s]{2,50}$ works as expected (excluding the spaces at the beginning)

Comment: So please check regex from the answer, I edited it. Thanks to the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446108/regular-expression-for-no-blank-space-b-w-text Cheers.

Comment: Yes, it works. In obj-c its NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^(?=\\S)()[A-Za-z\\s]{2,50}$"
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionUseUnicodeWordBoundaries
                                                                             error:&error];